# Print git log without commit messages

Tags: git

I like to look at my Git log like this

```
$ git log --graph --decorate --oneline -10 --all
```

but it includes commit messages. How do I hide messages and obtain something like this?

```
* e12ed2d (master)
*   d190591
|\
* | dd28b78
| | * 4f959a8 (how-many-branches-do-you-have?)
| |/
| | * 351e175 (yet-another-branch-name)
| |/
| | * c04425a (other-branch-name)
| |/
| | * d7f486c (branch-name)
| | * 530eeb2
| | * bf1ad62
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `--pretty=format:""` directive:

```
git log --graph --decorate -10 --all --pretty=format:"%Cred%h%Creset%C(yellow)%d%Creset"
```

You can see options available here (Table 2.1):

http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Viewing-the-Commit-History